# In selenium python, I only one to click on the second button, assuming there are 3 of the same buttons

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I am automating a process and there are 3 of the same button on a single webpage. However, I only want to click on the second button. Is there anyway I am able to that?

Here's the code for the button":

```
expandButtons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='expand-collapse']")
```

Comment: `expandButtons[1]`?

Comment: Check button attributes. They can't be exactly the same, so pick the one you want by his name or ID. What if they change order someday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expandButtons[1].click` will click 2nd button.